# NHibernate Linq with subquery returns 'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS'

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to get following query working:

```
var users = session.Query<PersonUser>()
.Select(u => new User()
{
    Id = u.UserId,
    FirstName = u.UserFirstName,
    Surname = u.UserSurname,
    ActiveRoles = u.Roles.Select(rr => new Role() { Id = rr.RoleId, DisplayName = rr.RoleName })
})
.ToList();
```

when I execute the query I get following:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException occurred
  Message=could not execute query
[ select personuser0_.USER_ID as col_0_0_, personuser0_.USER_FIRSTNAME as col_1_0_, personuser0_.USER_SURNAME as col_2_0_, (select personrole2_.ROLE_ID, personrole2_.ROLE_NAME from PERSON_ROLE_USER roles1_, PERSON_ROLE personrole2_ where personuser0_.USER_ID=roles1_.USER_ID and roles1_.ROLE_ID=personrole2_.ROLE_ID) as col_3_0_ from PERSON_USER personuser0_ ]
[SQL: select personuser0_.USER_ID as col_0_0_, personuser0_.USER_FIRSTNAME as col_1_0_, personuser0_.USER_SURNAME as col_2_0_, (select personrole2_.ROLE_ID, personrole2_.ROLE_NAME from PERSON_ROLE_USER roles1_, PERSON_ROLE personrole2_ where personuser0_.USER_ID=roles1_.USER_ID and roles1_.ROLE_ID=personrole2_.ROLE_ID) as col_3_0_ from PERSON_USER personuser0_]
  Source=NHibernate
  SqlString=select personuser0_.USER_ID as col_0_0_, personuser0_.USER_FIRSTNAME as col_1_0_, personuser0_.USER_SURNAME as col_2_0_, (select personrole2_.ROLE_ID, personrole2_.ROLE_NAME from PERSON_ROLE_USER roles1_, PERSON_ROLE personrole2_ where personuser0_.USER_ID=roles1_.USER_ID and roles1_.ROLE_ID=personrole2_.ROLE_ID) as col_3_0_ from PERSON_USER personuser0_

InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       Message=Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=1
       Number=116
       Procedure=""
       State=1
```

Note: `PersonUser` and `PersonRole` are POCO database entities and `User` and `Role` are simple DTO. `PersonUser.Roles` is List mapped HasManyToMany.

**How can I get NH to corectly project to `User` DTO including its many-to-many relations ship to `Role` DTO?**

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: NHibernate now does not support for such subqueries

Comment: I get the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

seems like sqlserver doesn't accept the query because the subquery returns more than one column. You can use:

```
var users = session.Query<PersonUser>()
    .Fetch(u => u.Roles).Eager
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(u => new User
    {
        Id = u.UserId,
        FirstName = u.UserFirstName,
        Surname = u.UserSurname,
        ActiveRoles = u.Roles.Select(rr => new Role { Id = rr.RoleId, DisplayName = rr.RoleName }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your works, but I would need to avoid loading all into memory, so I can't use `.AsEnumerable()` and without that it doesn't work.
I have appended .ToList() just for test. Actually I need to run more complex query, but I can't figure out how to correctly populate 'ActiveRoles'.

Comment: "I would need to avoid loading all into memory" Has PeronUser so many properties? Note: its still possible to set paging. Another way to only get what you need is `CreateSqlQuery` Or `IResultTransformer`